# Modal Box pushes html content to the side

Tags: html, modal-dialog, push

I'm using NyroModal but whenever you press "about me" or "my story" for the modal box popup it pushes the background html columns to the left. I made the wrapper 100% so I'm not sure why it keeps doing it.  http://imdarrien.com/

Comment: It seems that using the popup gives the `<body>` some extra styles, such as `width: 50%`. And then the floating columns no longer fit! I can't see where that happens though. Not familiar with nyroModal.

Comment: Hmm I tried playing around with the widths in the css but still couldn't get it to work properly.